# HTTP 525 Handshake Failed (Client-Side)

Tags: http, client-side

This week i started to get this error in multiple websites,not just one.
It can be from server-side too but i am getting this error from multiple websites. What is the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare's `525` error is usually due to an error with Cloudflare's connection to the origin server. In this case, it's the site's error and not your own. As a general rule of thumb, errors prefixed with `5--` are typically server errors while errors prefixed with `4--` are client errors.

Comment: It was not. I used a vpn and it works . Its weird. But thanks a lot!